# AWS RDS Database Instances secured and opensource data integrity checker

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, amazon-web-services

We are using `Oracle SE Two RDS engine` in our setup for taking backup in `AWS`. Does anybody have an idea of any data integrity tools (like `md5checksum`/`rsync` etc) available for `Oracle SE DB` which we can use `pre-restore` process?

Preferably secured and opensource and have moderate performance interms of time it takes for dataintegrity check for Oracle RDS instances.

```
RDS DB Engine Oracle SE Two 12.1.0.2.v8 .
```

If we will use MySQL DB as `RDS` instance do anyone know can we use `mysqldbcompare` tool for pre dataintegrity check for `RDB` instance considering the performance for large databases and security in mind?

If anyone knows any tools (preferably opensource), can you please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Use RMAN (recovery manager) for that, it is meant for that. I hope you also creates backup using this tool.
To validate a backup made with RMAN you can use the following:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmvalid.htm#BRADV89563